# Inno Setup - Animate Message Boxes as they are opened and closed

Tags: inno-setup

Is there any way to add some opening and closing animation to message boxes of inno setup?

Here is a link which explains some similar thing in Delphi:

https://delphidabbler.github.io/delphi-tips/tips/46.html

How to implement it inside inno setup?

Comment: I need to convert those Delphi functions into inno setup

Comment: something like this setup: https://web.archive.org/web/20150523082349/http://restools.hanzify.org/inno/ISSkinPack/ISSkinPack.exe, I believe the animation is not related to skin.

Comment: Could you please give a hand, Martin? :)